# Method name collision in different pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

In my cocoaPods different libraries I have a Date extension with 'isToday' variable. I use this var through the whole project thats why "ambiguous" appears. I really need both pods.
So I must leave both pods and resolve name collision conflict. Is there an explicit way to specify where to get 'isToday'.

Comment: can you mention those libraries?

Comment: SKExtension and DateToolsSwift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible

I can offer some solution to you, but check if all conditions fit for your case:

- Pods are open source
- Date Extensions are in separated files
- You don't need at least one of this file

You can remove unnecessary files from installed pod (after installation) using this script:

```
post_install do |installer|    
   require 'fileutils'  

   # Remove specific file from PodName
   FileUtils.rm 'Pods/{PodName}/{Path to unnecessary file}', :force => true # 'force' to ignore error, if file doesn't exist

   # Remove specific folder from PodName
   FileUtils.rm_rf 'Pods/{PodName}/{Path to unnecessary folder}'
end
```

Add it to the end of your `Podfile`